# How to put a variable in the path of a command being executed in a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

presently I'm working on a Bash script, and I am having trouble with writing a particular portion of the script.  Basically I read in an appName using the `read` command in the bash script, and then I want to run a command with the appName variable in the path, but when I run the script it just prints $appName not the variable itself.

The part of the script I am describing looks like the following,

```
echo "Input the name of the app"

read appName

echo "The AppName is: "$appName

dotApp=.app

ldid -S DerivedData/$appName/Build/Products/*/$appName$dotApp
```

Comment: Could you show the actual output and actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

The script you posted should work as is. Make sure the code you pasted is the actual code you run.

Putting single quotes around the string is the typical error that causes the problem you describe, but you don't have that in your posted example.

Comment: I think I have to use some combination of `eval` and `echo` to get the variable contents of `$appName` not the name of the variable itself.  As it currently stands ldid is trying to run with the variable name :/

Comment: You probably put your variable in single quotes at a point where they shouldn't be...

Comment: there's not single quotes in the script. when ldid runs it prints out an error message with `$appName` not the contents of the variable itself.

Comment: @Chris, can you run the script with `bash -x yourscript` and post the output?

Comment: @thatotherguy I think I figured it out, with your debugging help, and running the below line of code now works :)

`ldid -S DerivedData/$(echo $appName)/Build/Products/*/$(echo $appName).app/$(echo $appName)`

Comment: @Chris The `$(echo ..)`s are not necessary. Can you show a screenshot of the console where you cat then run the script you posted and get `$appName` in the output?